# how to remove words start with # from string

Tags: javascript

i have title like this "hello my #name is #ahmed kotsh"
and i want to remove #name #ahmed , any word start with # and the extra spaces after delete the hashtag

expect result "hello my is kotsh"
my try works but i know there is better code and more cleaner

```
const text = "hello my #name is #ahmed kotsh";
  const arr = text.split(" ");
  let newText = "";
  arr.map((i) => {
    if (i[0] != "#") newText = newText + i + " ";
  });
  console.log(newText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches `#` followed by non-space characters, and replace with nothing.

```js
const text = "hello my #name is #ahmed kotsh";
console.log(
  text.replace(/#\S+ ?/g, '')
);
```